# Adding class to specific cells of a html table

Tags: javascript, html, r, html-table

I am working on automating some reports for my company. We use R to summarize data in Excel, then use a combination of Rmarkdown, knitr, and the package "htmlTable" to create HTML.

I am currently using a CSS to modify some parts of the HTML code

```
markdownToHTML(paste0(basePath,'makeAppendixTableD1.md'),
             "appendixTableD1.html",
             stylesheet = paste0(basePath,"testStyleSheetUpdated.css"))
```

where the HTML code output from above looks like:

```
<table class='gmisc_table' style='border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;' >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: center;'>X1</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: center;'>X2</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>0.35</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: center;'>X3</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>0.31</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I can easily change the attributes like font-size or font-family using the CSS; however, I am a bit stumped for how to best edit specific columns or rows.

For example, I'd like to make X2 to be bold and italicized. But **I won't always know where X2 is in the table**. So I can't put in the CSS to modify the second row, first cell as for another table X2 may be the 10th row, first cell.

EDIT: Ideally, I'd like to be able to edit the whole `<tr>` `</tr>` for when X2 exists in the HTML.

Currently, I can use `gsub()` and some other string functions to find X2 in the HTML, then go back a couple characters to insert class = "X2". But this involves a fair bit of hardcoding.

Is there an easier way to do this using javaScript? I've looked into using the xtable package in R. There doesn't seem to be a way to add classes using the htmlTable package in R.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? It would be fairly easy to check the contents of a `<td>` with jQuery and then add a class accordingly.

Comment: I've thought about using jQuery, but the software I'm developing will be used be on other machines and not necessarily by me. I know you have to install a .js file on the computer that is using the jQuery code - not sure the best way to implement using jQuery at my work at the moment.

Comment: why can't you just match the text and put whatever tags around it? for example `htmlTable(mtcars); x <- 4;; mtcars[mtcars == x] <- sprintf('<strong><em>%d</em></strong>', x); htmlTable(mtcars)`

Comment: @rawr That is a good idea for modifying cells - but I should have added to the original post that I'd like to edit the whole <tr> </tr>. For example, if we use your code: `x <- 'Volvo 142E'; mtcars[mtcars == x] <- sprintf('<strong><em>%d</em></strong>', x)` but instead have all rows have the same `'<strong><em>%d</em></strong>'` property for that Volvo 142E row. I'm editing the original post now.

Comment: so that would be just `x <- 'Volvo 142E'; mtcars[x, ] <- sapply(mtcars[x, ], function(xx) sprintf('<strong><em>%s</em></strong>', xx)); htmlTable(mtcars)` I only pass matrices to htmltable, it makes formatting much easier and more consistent

Comment: @rawr Your method works but I wanted to add some additional properties. For example, make the top and bottom border black for the whole row. That won't work when modifying individual cells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With vanilla JS, you could do something like:

```
//grab all td elements in your table
var tds = document.querySelectorAll(".gmisc_table td");
//iterate over each td
for (var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
  var text = tds[i].innerText;
  //check for your target text
  if (text === "X2") {
    //add your class to the element containing this text
    tds[i].classList.add("X2");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Seagrass. This seems to work - is there a way to modify the parent <tr> corresponding to the td that has `text === "X2"` as well once the td element is found?

Comment: Sure, given that `tds[i]` is the td with the parent you want to modify, you could access the parent using `tds[i].parentElement`

Answer (score 2):

Pure JS:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementsByTagName("td"), 0 )
  .filter(function(x) {return x.innerHTML.match(/X2/)})
  .forEach(function(x) {
             x.classList.add('X2')                          // <td>
             x.parentNode.classList.add('OtherClassName')   // <tr>
  })
```

The last `x` is the DOM representation of the `<td>`, so you can navigate from there wherever you like, as the last line does with `x.parentNode` which is the `<tr>`...

jQuery on the first line only:

```
$.makeArray($("td"))
  .filter(function(x) {return x.innerHTML.match(/X2/)})
  .forEach(function(x) {x.classList.add('X2')})
```

ES6 with jQuery (won't work in IE11 due to no support for `=>` yet):

```
$.makeArray($("td"))
  .filter(x => x.innerHTML.match(/X2/))
  .forEach(x => x.classList.add('X2'))
```

You would change line two to filter for an exact match if you so desired:

```
.filter(function(x) {return x.innerHTML === 'X2'})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];


var cols = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
  
  var col = cols[i];
  
  var content = col.innerText;
  
  // If it starts with 'X':
  if (content[0] === 'X') {
    col.className = content;
  }
}
```

```css
.X1 { color: red; }
.X2 { color: blue; }
```

```html
<table class='gmisc_table' style='border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;' >
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: center;'>X1</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: center;'>X2</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>0.35</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align: center;'>X3</td>
<td style='text-align: center;'>0.31</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```